# substring is not a function - number won't change to string

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem where I can't seem to convert a simple number to string?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tostring_number

https://stackabuse.com/javascript-convert-number-to-string/

```js
var singleVariantPrice = 400;
singleVariantPrice.toString();
console.log('type is: ' + typeof singleVariantPrice);
```

What's wrong with this? Why is `typeof` still giving me number...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the new value to `singleVariantPrice`:

```js
var singleVariantPrice = 400;
singleVariantPrice = singleVariantPrice.toString();
console.log('type is: ' + typeof singleVariantPrice);
```

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/javascript-convert-number-to-string/ - how come they dont do that in this link?

Comment: @kawnah ?? that article *does* do that. Every example involves an assignment to a variable.

Comment: @kawnah in those examples they're just showing the return value of .toString(), not assigning it to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Primitives (including numbers and strings) are immutable. `toString` returns a *new* expression, without changing what was in the variable it was called on.

You need to assign the `toString` call to *another* variable, then examine that variable:

```js
var singleVariantPrice = 400;
const str = singleVariantPrice.toString();
console.log('type is: ' + typeof str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:

```
var singleVariantPrice = 400;
Number(singleVariantPrice).toString();
console.log('type is: ' + typeof singleVariantPrice);
```